# Is there a mode-hook when you switch to a buffer in Eshell mode

Tags: hooks, eshell

For my function, that I have created, I'm looking for an Eshell mode hook.

I'm aware of the following hook:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'my-function-for-eshell).
```

But what when I'm in a other buffer and want to switch back to the existing buffer with Eshell mode, I want to run that function? 
But I found all the hooks only will be triggered, when you create a new buffer with an Eshell mode.

To be clear, I run Evil normal mode when I do switch buffers with a keybinding in normal mode.
The `my-function-for-eshell` brings me back in Evil insert mode, when I go back to Eshell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no hook specifically for switching buffers, but you can use the `buffer-list-update-hook`. Switching buffers re-orders the buffer list and triggers this hook, so you could use that to run a command that checks the major-mode of the current buffer and takes some action if it is eshell.

Comment: It might add a large overhead because Eshell is a tiny part of my workflow, and I switch buffers a lot. But better than nothing, thanks for that!

Comment: How about your own command to switch to your eshell buffer and run whatever additional commands you need?

Comment: Not possible, because when I split my window, my Eshell window lies adjacent. I have a default keybinding where I can navigate to all windows. When I want to Eshell window, I need another keybinding then in order to call my own command. But thanks for the suggestion, a good idea anyway.